# MiniProfiler on WebForms and .NET35 Classic Mode

Tags: webforms, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm new to MiniProfiler and trying to get it working on a legacy codebase.

- NET35 WebForms project
- using https://github.com/mmooney/MiniProfiler
- Running on IIS8 .NET2 Managed Pipline: Classic

mmooney's fork uses .NET35 but runs under .NET4 on IIS.

I get nothing displayed from MP:

[image]
No sure what this 404 actually means.

If I change to .NET4 and Integrated Managed Pipeline it will work.

Have tried different web.config settings including

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--<handlers>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>-->
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Am trying a different tactic now of running the app under .NET4 and Managed Pipeline: Integrated.  So, on the shiny happy path for Miniprofiler and it is working now.

Comment: I couldn't get it work in ASP.NET either and had to give up :(